# PYQT5 QComboBox change item text

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am using PQT5 and would like change the text of a qcombobox item. 
Eg.:

Item1: Hello
Item2: World
Item3: ?

How can I change Item3 from "?" to "!"?

I didn't find anything (google/stackoverflow) that helped me.
Thank you in advance for helping me.

Cheers Loki

Edit:
A code example as requested:

```
   mycombo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
   mycombo.addItem("Hello")
   mycombo.addItem("World")
   mycombo.addItem("?")
```

Now I want to change the text of the second or last item. As I said, I didn't find something while searching.

Comment: It would help if you post your source code...

Comment: `mycombo.setItemText(2, '!')`